# Social Engine send user after registration to custom page

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

When user registers on my SocialEngine website - how can I redirect him to one of my custom pages that are created inside SE4 (located at `mydomain.com/index.php/pages/custompage`)?

Is there a way to integrate my page into signup process?

Answer (score 2):

Use the hook `onUserSignUpAfter` to redirect the user to the desired page.

If you don't mind editing the SE4 files as a way to customize it then you may do the following on the any active modules. Otherwise you must put the following in a separate module. Find the manifest file of the module you selected to edit or created (let's say we edit `application/modules/Core`). Find or add the 'hooks' key and add the onUserSignupAfter like so:

```
    'hooks' => array(
      array(
        'event' => 'onUserSignupAfter',
        'resource' => 'Core_Plugin_Core'
      )
    )
```

Edit Core_Plugin_Core and add the method:

```
    public function onUserSignupAfter($event)
    {
      header('Location: /page/my_custom_page');
      exit;
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific? Do I include that in the signup process files or my custom page?

Comment: Here is an example of an SE4 hook http://social-engine-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/03/social-engine-4-hook-example.html. In the body of the callback just do the redirection.

Comment: After trawling Google for hours and trying many other solutions, I found this and it works +1 @marco. Why has this not been marked as correct?